# how to do thread operations in android

Tags: android, multithreading, sd-card

Anyone give example program which explains android Threads in a simpler way. For example, i want to list out the songs in a sd card in thread at the time of launch

i am using the following code to get the number of songs in sd card of an android device. From this i want to list out the songs in thread

```
private void init_phone_sd_card() 
    {   
        System.gc();
        final String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE };
        Log.e("media",""+proj);

        musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
        Log.e("media1",""+musiccursor);

        count = musiccursor.getCount();
        Log.e("media2",""+count);
```

how to do this......

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your code to AsyncTask's doInBackground() method. Task also should show ProgressDialog in order to tell user that some useful work is running. See [this](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en) article.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for a simple thread operation, [this will help](http://saeedsiam.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-look-into-android-thread.html) you..

Or you might want to use Async class like the one below,

```
    class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        for (String item : items) {
            publishProgress(item);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }

        return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
        ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add(item[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Toast
            .makeText(Async.this, 
                    "Done",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a *simpler* explanation. Simpler than what?

Have a look at the [Android Process and Thread fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) and the [painless threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article and its `AsyncTask` sections.